# Under what circumstances would two identical subdomains on the same server behave differently?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I have two subdomains in the same parent folder on the same disk on the same physical server, operating under the same instance of Apache2 and all its mods. How do I know the folders are identical? Because I did this:

```
cd ~/projects/subdomain2
rm -rf *
cd ../
cp -rf --preserve=all subdomain1/* subdomain2/
```

I'm having a very specific problem on subdomain2 - specifically, IE refuses to maintain sessions for the webapp my team's developing in subdomain2, but subdomain1 the sessions are preserved correctly between page loads. That's neither here nor there; at this point I don't care *why* is isn't working, only that subdomain1 solves that problem...somehow. What I *am* asking is, why would two identical directories, with the same .htaccess rules and the same virtualhost configurations, behave differently? Any other guesses what might be causing the inconsistencies?

Comment: Where are the sessions stored ? Are there any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: Sessions are being handled by memcached. There is an error log being generated by the application for subdomain2 that isn't being generated by subdomain1, but it's not being thrown and handled by the application's error handler, just sent to the log. Which is...weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other visitors' benefit, we solved the issue. (I work with mounty.) The issue was that subdomain1 was actually sub_domain1 (i.e., included an underscore), and IE doesn't accept cookies from domains with underscores. Technically this is not a bug, as IE is following the RFC-2396 spec more strictly, but it's the only browser to do so.

Authority:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316112

Comment: May as well include some crosstalk from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies